# What's the meaning of "the column's impediment"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, sentence

> We see atop Arlington Ridge, **the column's impediment** of Arlington
>   House, which is now the Robert E. LEE Memorial.

([CNN Transcripts](http://www.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1502/17/sn.01.html); video and audio: [CNN Student News](http://linkengpark.com/cnn-student-news-with-transcript-week-8-2015/))

What's the meaning of "the column's impediment" in the above sentence? When I interpret impediment as an obstacle, this sentence doesn't make a sense to me.

Comment: This source says [THIS IS A RUSH TRANSCRIPT. THIS COPY MAY NOT BE IN ITS FINAL FORM AND MAY BE UPDATED](http://www.listeningexpress.com/cnn/cnnstudentnews/CNNSN-2015-02-17-CNN-Student-News.html) (their caps, not mine! :)  Perhaps the speaker is referring to Arlington House as impeding the advance of [a column of] the Civil War soldiers he was talking about earlier.

Comment: That transcript is full of errors.  Consider _though the door is clothes to us_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a discussion of monuments, including a Greek-revival style mansion that's the [Robert E Lee Memorial](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Arlington_House_front_view.JPG).  It's likely that the words are "columns and pediment."  From the ground to the roof, the architectural elements are (in a simplified list)

- [pedestal](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pedestal?q=pedestal)
- column [base](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/base_1?q=base)
- [column](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/column?q=column) shaft
- column [capital](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/capital_1?q=capital)
- [entablature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entablature)
- [pediment](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pediment?q=pediment)

The entablature is a horizontal structure that sits on the column capitals and supports the triangular pediment.

Comment: It's definitely "the columns and pediment"

Comment: The picture link works for me now! (But, why put it behind a link rather than embedding it in your answer?)

Comment: Fixed link and quote.  And, no, the original apostrophe did not indicate "possession."

Comment: @sumelic I'm a word kinda guy.  Not a visual kinda guy.